# How to change screen if you're moving forward and see older things if you move backwards?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am working on a game project, and I am stuck with a situation. So I have a game object that if moves towards right and then enters again into the screen on the left (pacman effect) there is a new screen, I mean the screen is the same, but there should be with new other objects, but if the game object goes back, I should be able to see the older version of objects on the screen. So I have a list of lists of planets. I created them, and the thing I would like to "print" the the first element of the list if move forward, and if I move backwards I would like to see the previous element. I did think to try to use a circular version, but I decided I will not do that. 
https://imgur.com/a/vCjk9iW

```
class planet {
//an shape planet has these charateristics
sf::CircleShape shape;
 //etc
 };

struct nodeplanet 
{
planet Planet;
nodeplanet *planet;
}

typedef nodeplanet *ptr_listplanet;

//here I make a list with planet

 class listofplanets
{
private:
ptr_listplanet head;
public:
listofplanets()
{
head = NULL;
}
ptr_listofplanets create ()
//etc;
};

//then i create a system of planets;

   struct nodeSystem 
  {
 listofplanets ListOfPlanets;
  nodeSystem*next;
  nodeSystem *prev;
  }
  ptr_listSystem GenerateNode()
{
    ptr_listSystem tmp;
    tmp = new nodeSystem;
    tmp->ListOfPlanets = ListOfPlanets();
    tmp->ListOfPlanets.create(randomnumber());
    tmp->prev = NULL;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}
ptr_listSystem GenerateSystem ()
{

  for (int i=0; i<3; i=i+1){ //just a trial, creating three systems
        ptr_listSistema newNode = GenerateNode();
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = head;
       if (head!=NULL)
        head->prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    return this->head;
}
void Visualize(sf::RenderWindow &window, Player player)
{ 
    ptr_listSistema current = this->head;

        float x;
        //while (current!=NULL){
                x = player.shape.getPosition().x;
       current->ListOfPlanet.draw(window);
       //if ((player.shape.getPosition().x > 1269))
       if (x>1269)
      {
          //current = GenerateSystem();
          current = current->next;


            window.clear();
            current->ListaPianeta.draw(window);

      }
       //if ((player.shape.getPosition().x< 3) && (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))) 
      {
          if ((x<3) && (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)))
          //p = current->prev;
          current = current->prev;
          if (current == NULL)
          {
              current = current->next; //in the case I am in the "head" screen, I should see the head screen; 
          }

          window.clear();
          current->ListOfPlanet.draw(window); 
      }

       // }
}
```

the visualize function is the classic printing function of the list. at least I think, the list is already generated, if the player moves forward i should be able to see the planets generated in the next node, and if the player moves backwards i should be able to see the the previous node. I tried with the loop, using the while, but it's not that i should keep "printing", it depends. (I don't know if my idea is logically corrected)

Answer (score 0):

Think you can simplify everything a lot. Just draw everything where it actually is. Then use a `sf::View` to represent the current visible screen and move that around accordingly:

```cpp
// setup done only once, we'll reposition it later
sf::View screen(sf::Vector2(0,0), sf::Vector2(screen_width, screen_height));

// before drawing
screen.setCenter((std::floor(player.shape.getPosition().x / screen_width) + 0.5f) * screen_width, screen_height / 2);
window.setView(screen);
```

What this basically does is calculating the intended left border position of the screen (by dividing, rounding, then multiplying the screen width) and adjusting this with an offset for the screen center (the `+ 0.5f`).

Obviously you could also duplicate the code for the X coordinate and reuse it for Y as well, allowing up/down transitions as well:

```cpp
screen.setCenter((std::floor(player.shape.getPosition().x / screen_width) + 0.5f) * screen_width, (std::floor(player.shape.getPosition().y / screen_height) + 0.5f) * screen_height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment; now is it screen the same as window? and so in the function view, i should also add the "printing" function of the system of planets; while (current!=NULL) { current->ListOfPlanets.draw(window); current = current->next; }

Comment: @throwawayinvisible With this idea you'd just draw everything, even if it's off-screen (although this can be optimized). A `sf::View` determines which part of your "world" is actually visible on screen. Other libraries and engines might call it a camera.

Comment: the idea is that if the player moves forward there is a "new world" and if it goes back, it shows the previous one. so my idea was to have each node of a linked list a "world" and on the basis of the player movement, i can go forwards, so i have new worlds and if i go back, the older one.  from what i have understood about the view function, seems to be a camera, and i am not sure if that effectively is what i am looking for.